# Why should I use one-to-one (has_one) association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database, rails-activerecord

Why should I use `has_one` association (and additional table, model), when I can embed associated object and use `composed_of` and/or `serialize`. In cases when I always join associated object and don't need complex queries.  For example:

Dog(color,weight) `has_one :head` Head(teeth_count,eye_color)

I can replace by Dog(color,weight,head_teeth_count,head_eye_color) and use "calculated attribute" or value objects like

`composed_of :head, mapping: [%w(head_teeth_count teeth_count), %w(head_eye_color eye_color)]`

Less tables, simpler, code clearer, less heavy models, no accidental extra queries, better performance.

Another example:

User(email) `has_many :roles` Role(name)

transforms into User(email,roles)

`serialize :roles, Array`

I missed something in these cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semantics, which are actually a pretty important part of writing good software.

A book is not composed of an author. A book *has* an author.

I would also argue that you're sorely mistaken about your example being simpler or having clearer code. The performance improvement is debatable, and likely negligible.

Your last case is particularly bad. What if you want to search for all users in a specific role? Instantiate all users, deserialize and check one at a time?

Comment: Well, here http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association rbates use bitmask, that is also a strange decision (save bits for green earth?). Search for users with some role – ok, that's not a good case for my example.